# a regex for numbers, letters, and -_. but the -_. can't be last characters of the captured fragment

Tags: ruby, regex

How would I create a regex that captures as follows:

```
"bs BN12.3.-".scan(regex) # => [["12.3"]]
```

where the trailing periods, underscores, and hyphens are not included in the capture but the internal ones are? I tried the following:

```
"bs BN12.3.-".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)/) # => [["12.3.-"]]
```

Comment: Inside `[...]` a hyphen has special meaning *unless* it's the last character seen: `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]` is how you should write your set. Also, `.` inside the set loses its special meaning, along with `-` so neither have to be escaped. Knowing how patterns work will let you write them more cleanly/clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your existing group non-greedy by ending it with `?` as in `([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+?)` and follow it with an expression that matches the other characters `[-._]*` before terminating with `$`, you should get what you need:

```
"bs BN12.3.-".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+?)[-._]*$/)
 => [["12.3"]]

# Different input strings...
"bs BN12.3".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+?)[-._]*$/)
 => [["12.3"]] 
2.1.0 :012 > "bs BN12.".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+?)[-._]*$/)
 => [["12"]]
"bs BN12.3-4.5______".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+?)[-._]*$/)
 => [["12.3-4.5"]]
```

(Note: most of the punctuation characters don't require escaping inside the `[]` character class. The hyphen does in its current position, but wouldn't if move to the end of the `[]`)

Addendum: To prevent *any* non-alphabetic, non-digit character at the end, the final character class can be `[^A-Za-z0-9]*`

```
"bs BN12.3-4.5______".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+?)[^A-Za-z0-9]*$/)
 => [["12.3-4.5"]]
```

Comment: Good, straight forward solution. Bonus points for mentioning most characters do not require escaping inside a character class. Happens so often people escape things like `.` inside a character class when they do not have to.

Comment: hmm.... is there any way I can adjust for allowing anything in that second expression that isn't [a-zA-Z0-9]? Like !, :, or something else. Basically, it ends if it is not [a-zA-Z0-9]? Our data has things like `"bs BN12.3-4.5!"` which are not appearing. thx

Comment: @timpone Yes, that makes more sense to end with `[^A-Za-z]*`  Negation is via `^`. I'll add it above.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to set one of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to end the match and change the quantifier of `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]` from `+` to `*` any amount of times:

```
 (?<=BN)[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Additional used a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for matching `BN` to start the match for avoiding the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

To make it shorter, might use some [shorthands](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html):

```
(?<=BN)[-\w.]*[^\W_]
```

[Test on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sK4hO0)

Comment: That's a very nice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ones you don't want to capture in a non-capture group, for example, instead of saying something like `([-\.\_]*)` you would put the non capture symbol `?:`, like `(?:[-\.\_]*)`.

Comment: would that still get me internal ones though?

Comment: If you put it at the end, something like `/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+?)(?:[-\.\_]*)$/`

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you mean by 'internal'? Which ones are 'internal'?